# mysql table creation Error Code: 1005 in this specific case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried everything in solving this issue and yes I know that this type of question is already asked here but I could not solve my issue
It is `mysql` database

```
 Error Code: 1005

Can't create table '.\project\comments.frm' (errno: 150)
```

the foreign keys are matching in structure (i.e `length` and `type`) then what can be the possible problem in the table creation

Table which is giving error is `comments`:

```
 CREATE TABLE `comments`(
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `post_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts`.`id`,
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`.`id`,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
```

Here is posts table which is already created in the databas

```
 CREATE TABLE `posts` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `title` varchar(30) default NULL,
   `description` longtext,
   `image` varchar(50) default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the users table which is also already created in the database

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `user_name` varchar(33) default NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `registrationDate` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`email`,`type`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  The `REFERENCES` keyword should be followed by `table (columns)`:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments`(
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `post_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```